# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.applibrary.R$layout

Tags: android

Edit : Solved. How? Nut sure, but an user commented on my questions about errors in res-folder could make this happen. Didn't have errors in this folder, but a warning about an image that was not used. Removed this and other possible causes to warnings, recompiled and uploaded to Play. It works...

--

I've made an app that works fine running on both the emulator and device. If I export then app and the install the app on my device, it works. But when I've published it on Play and install it from there, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.applibrary.R$layout
at com.applibrary.ANEivActivity.onCreate(ANEivActivity.java:179)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error just occured during a bugfix that was related to something else than R or any thing else that remotely can have done anything with the project setup. Seems like applibrary is lost when published on Play(?).

My app uses a library called applibrary and most of the code, including java, layout, string, is located in this library.

How come this error only occurs when the app is downloaded from Play and not run as mentioned on emulator and device?

I've tried 'Fix Project Properties', 'Clean'.